# How to upload multiple files with carrierwave and create multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am trying to modify my image upload routine in order to upload multiple images at the same time. Currently I am able to upload multiple images, but it creates only one record. How can I achieve it that one submit creates multiple records?

I do not want to go through an association, but instead be able to directly upload multiple images.

I currently have a Model:

```
class Diapo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :album
  mount_uploaders :file_name, DiapoUploader
end
```

My Controller:

```
class Admin::DiaposController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @diapo = Diapo.new
    @page_title = 'Create new Diapo'
  end

  def create
    @diapo = Diapo.new(diapo_params)
    if @diapo.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Diapo #{@diapo.file_name} was successfully created.
      redirect_to action: :index
    else
      @page_title = 'Create new Diapo'
      render action: :new
    end
  end

.
.
.

  private

  def diapo_params
    params.require(:diapo).permit({file_name: []}, :title, :alt, :author, :copyright, :album_id)
  end
end
```

in the form I have:

```
<%= f.file_field :file_name, multiple: true, class: 'form-field' %>
```

Currently I get one post

```
Started POST "/admin/diapos" for ::1 at 2019-12-18 10:45:19 +0100
Processing by Admin::DiaposController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"something==", "diapo"=>{"file_name"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f9062b51a40 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/yg/pfjwzpkx5wq9d27svk760h0h0000gn/T/RackMultipart20191218-2329-7kffxo.jpg>, @original_filename="1.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"diapo[file_name][]\"; filename=\"1.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f9062b519f0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/yg/pfjwzpkx5wq9d27svk760h0h0000gn/T/RackMultipart20191218-2329-o5qzhe.jpg>, @original_filename="2.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"diapo[file_name][]\"; filename=\"2.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">], "alt"=>"Test", "author_ids"=>"", "album_id"=>"124", "copyright"=>"Test"}, "commit"=>"Save"}
  Admin Load (0.4ms)  SELECT 'admins'.* FROM 'admins' WHERE 'admins'.'id' = 1 ORDER BY 'admins'.'id' ASC LIMIT 1
Unpermitted parameter: :author_ids
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/admin/diapos_controller.rb:14:in `create'
  Album Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `albums`.* FROM `albums` WHERE `albums`.`id` = 124 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/admin/diapos_controller.rb:14:in `create'
  Diapo Create (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `diapos` (`file_name`, `alt`, `copyright`, `album_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('[\"1.jpg\", \"2.jpg\"]', 'Test', 'Test', 124, '2019-12-18 09:45:34.406410', '2019-12-18 09:45:34.406410')
  ↳ app/controllers/admin/diapos_controller.rb:14:in `create'
   (6.5ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/admin/diapos_controller.rb:14:in `create'
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admin/diapos
Completed 302 Found in 15350ms (ActiveRecord: 7.5ms | Allocations: 75512)
```

and 1 record is created which has the array of filenames in the filename field.

I suspect I can do it either in the controller or through javascript? How would I do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement your requirement with **has_many** relation.
To save multiple record you may have parent child relationship just like below.

Ex :- 
Post is a parent table and save its images as post_attachments which is child table

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :post_attachments
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_attachments
end

class PostAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base
   mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
   belongs_to :post
end
```

this is how you can achieve to save multiple files for parent record

For more detail see this [Article](https://kolosek.com/carrierwave-upload-multiple-images/) which may be helpful to you.

https://kolosek.com/carrierwave-upload-multiple-images/

Comment: Thanks @code_aks I was aware of the has_many option, but I am looking for something which is able to achieve the same thing without has_many. I just have Images, no post or something similar exists before upload. Maybe a custom controller action which loops through a create?

Comment: Above is just an example you can fulfil your requirement in the same way which is more easier than any loop or javascript. :)

Comment: Dear code_aks I got it nearly working, but I am unable to write multiple attributes to the nested_form. Could you maybe take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/q/59414743/4779531 Thanks

Comment: Sure I will try in sometime probably at night. :)